# Line 93:6: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'estado'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Tags: reactjs

Can someone help me please?
I have the following problem!!

**Line 93:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'estado'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps**

```
  const [nome, setNome] = useState("");
  const [sobreNome, setSobreNome] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [dataNascimento, setDataNascimento] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [estado, setEstado] = useState();
  const [cidade, setCidade] = useState();   
  const [lojas, setLojas] = useState();
  const [valueEstado, setValueEstado] = useState([]);
  const [valueUnidade, setValueUnidade] = useState([]);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    let arr = [];
    unidades.map((item) => {
      if (estado === item.UF) {
        arr.push(item.Cidade);
      }
      return true
    });
    
    setValueEstado(arr);
  }, [estado]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let arr = [];
    unidades.map((item) => {
      if (cidade === item.Cidade && estado === item.UF) {
        arr.push({ Loja: item.Loja, CodigoFilial: item.CodigoFilial });
      }
      return true
    });
    setValueUnidade(arr);
  }, [cidade]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second useEffect accesses the state variable "estado" but you don't list it in the dependency array (the second argument of useEffect). Note, this will cause your second useEffect to rerun anytime "estado" changes.

Comment: Could you rewrite the code the right way to do it?

Comment: @LucasSilva Your second useEffect should look like this `useEffect(() => {...}, [cidade, estado])`

Comment: You are the best , man

Comment: Solved my problem , thank you so much